# Primefaces client bean validation not working

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces client bean validation but it is not working,error messages disappears.Listener is called even when validation fails.

Sample-
xhtml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:i="http://kd.impakt2/tags">


<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="images.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>




    <h:form id="parentForm">
        <p:growl id="msgs" sticky="true" ></p:growl>
        <p:inputText value="#{myBean.selCar.name}"></p:inputText>
        <p:commandButton  value="Click Me" validateClient="true">

            <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{myBean.callMe}"
                 update="msgs" process="@form"></p:ajax>

        </p:commandButton>


    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

Java-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;
import org.primefaces.model.SortOrder;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

@ManagedBean(name = "myBean")
 public class MyBean {



Car selCar;

public Car getSelCar() {
    return selCar;
}

public void setSelCar(Car selCar) {
    this.selCar = selCar;
}



public MyBean() {


    selCar = new Car();


}



public void callMe(){
    System.out.println("Hi");
}

 }
```

Car.java-

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.primefaces.component.export.Exporter;

@Entity
public class Car {

@Id
String id;

@Size(min=1,max=2)
String name;


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

But this works-

```
    <p:commandButton  value="Click Me" validateClient="true" action="#{myBean.callMe}">
```

After debugging i found out that when listener is called messages get displayed but once it completes message disappears.

I am using-
Primefaces 4
Jsf 2.2.6(mojarra)
tomcat 7

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: What you want to validates here?

Comment: i m using JSR-303 annotation @size on name to validate name length.

Comment: Why don't you use validator method for an input field?

Comment: Because once i apply JSR validation on server side it automatically works on client side.So need of validator method.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. In `JSF` forms each fields has its own validator method . Did  you aware of that one?

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that but i want to use JSR validation annotations as PrimeFaces directly works with these annotations without writing any extra code.But somehow it is not working in the case of AJAX request.

Comment: Do you have primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION set as true in web.xml?

Comment: Yes i have primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION set true in my web.xml.Validations are working when i use action but it is not working for p:ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Everything started working by downgrading JSF 2.2.6 to JSF 2.2.2