# Using with JSF - HIbernate validation fails (javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf-2

I'm using JSF, Spring and Hibernate. Post model has Hibernate annotated attributes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private int version;

    @Column(name = "title")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Title should not be empty")
    private String title;

    ... getters/setters

}
```

When I try to create a new Post in the corresponding bean(disregard syntax proper à pretty-faces) :

```
@Component
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
@URLMappings(mappings = {
        @URLMapping(id = "posts", pattern = "/posts/", viewId = "/faces/posts/list.xhtml"),
        @URLMapping(id = "new", pattern = "/posts/new", viewId = "/faces/posts/new.xhtml")
})
public class PostBean {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    private List<Post> posts;

    private Post post = new Post();

    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return postService.findAll();
    }

    public Post getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(Post post) {
        this.post = post;
    }

    public String create(Post post) {
        this.post = postService.save(post);
        return "pretty:posts";
    }
}
```

PostRepository:

```
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long> {
    public Post findByTitleIgnoreCase(String title);
}
```

PostServiceImpl:

```
@Service("postService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Post> findAll() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(postRepository.findAll());
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Post findById(Long id) {
        return postRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Post findByTitleIgnoreCase(String title) {
        return postRepository.findByTitleIgnoreCase(title);
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Post save(Post post) {
        return postRepository.save(post);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy(Post post) {
        postRepository.delete(post);
    }
}
```

I get the `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`. Strange is that if remove Hibernate annotation and put `required="true"` directly into the JSF page aside to the title textfield, it works.

```
<h:inputText id="title" value="#{postBean.post.title}" required="true"/>
```

Any idea ? You can find the project code source at [my github repo](https://github.com/Javix/blog-jsf)
Thank you.

@NotNull is a JSR303 validation, @NotEmpty - is the one by Hibernate, that is the only difference. Even after changing for @NotNull I still get the same error.

[update] By the way, I removed @ManagedBean annotation, it is not needed anymore.
[update-2] @AVolpe: It will change nothing, just move the message to be displayed aside of the title textfield. The error happens when calling:

```
public String create(Post post) {
        this.post = postService.save(post);
        return "pretty:posts";
    }
```

Comment: Try adding the annotation `@NotNull` to your property, for `Bean-Validation` a property `null` without the `@NotNull` annotation is allways valid.

Comment: Try add a `<h:message for="title" />` after the `inputText`.

Comment: Adding h:message for title will just display the error for title attribute.Error happens when calling postService.save(post).

Comment: I download your project and test it, I have many errors, but the original problemn don't occur (the validation works fine), I tested it with a jboss 7.1 (see http://postimg.org/image/pf31hehd1/), btw I have so many problem with the URL creation.

Comment: Right, I kept the working version. If you remove required="true" from posts/new page, and add @NotNull to the title attribute in the domain/Post.java, you will get the error. Just run mvm clean install to get all the dependencies and run the project on your server (I used Tomcat).

Comment: You can checkout the branch that raises the error from https://github.com/Javix/blog-jsf/tree/bean_validation

Comment: I deploy the requested version and the validation work's, see http://postimg.org/image/4sfiw61cf/. It's works with `@NotNull`, `@NotEmpty`, and `required = "false"`. Btw, I use a Jboss.

Comment: Not for me: http://postimg.org/image/kkuucqrct/. Be sure to redeploy the project from the bean_validation branch, please.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780474/primefaces-client-bean-validation-not-working it's maybe a problem with your JSF version, I change the scope in my machine to `provided` (because the jboss have the dependencies) and it's works fine. See this error report https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3183
It's seems that if you downgrade the version to 2.2.4 (or upgrade to 2.27) its works fine.

Comment: Bravo! Fixed after upgrading com.sun.faces to 2.2.7. THANKS A LOT! I'll merge the fixed branch into master.

Comment: Please mark my answers as the correct one!, cheers, and thanks for make your project openSource, please add a licence.

Answer (score 1):

Because [this error](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3183) the version `2.2.6` of `JSF` don't work well with `BeanValidation`, update to the version `2.2.7` or downgrade to `2.2.4`.

See:
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780474/primefaces-client-bean-validation-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by upgrading jsf version up 2.2.7 as suggested by AVolpe.