# bean validation (JSR 303) for primefaces not working

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, bean-validation

I'm using:

- Primefaces 6.1
- JSF: 2.2.10
- javax.validation:1.1.0.Final
- validator impl: hibernate-validator 5.0.1.Final
- GAE: 1.9.52

I follow the example for CSV (Client Side Validation) using backend bean from:
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/bean.xhtml

The expected result should be:
[image]

And what I get right now:

[image]

The bean validation is not working.

I have below configure in web.xml

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name> 
    <param-value>true</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Few similar posts said need downgrade jsf to 2.2.2, I tried but still not working.

Right now the workaround for CSV is either

- using jsf tag validation based on the demo

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/basic.xhtml

For example:

```
<p:inputText id="age" value="#{beanValidationView.age}" label="Age">
    <f:validateLongRange for="age" minimum="10" maximum="20" />
</p:inputText>
```

- Or create my own validator

for example:
http://www.supermanhamuerto.com/doku.php?id=java:validatorinprimefaces

BTW, I don't think it is related to GAE.  Because I tried with a new Dynamic Web Project using Tomcat 9, it give me the same result as shown in below screen capture.

[image]

Is that any thing(s) I miss configured or having diff version of jar causing that problem?

Comment: _"Few similar post said need downgrade jsf to 2.2.2, I tried but not working."_ I cannot imagine this... Can you post a link? And since you tagged it 'google-app-engine' does that mean it works on Tomcat? And 'javax.validation' is the API, did you include an implementation? And 'csv' is client-side, not specifically 'bean validation'  And did you follow the documentation?

Comment: Here the link that other solved it by downgrade jsf from 2.2.6 to 2.2.2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780474/primefaces-client-bean-validation-not-working

Comment: The javax.validator I used in pom.xml is from below link.  I believe it is just api as you said.  Any link for implementation I can get?  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final

Comment: Try goole... it is your friend

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, I tag GAE because that is the server I used.  Have not try out on tomcat yet.

Comment: Tags are for where the problem (likely) is, not what you use. You use java, html, css, javascript etc...

Comment: Hi mate...  I include the validator implementation: hibernate-validator 5.4.1.Final from below link, but bean validation still not working.  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator

Comment: Hi.  I tried with tomcat 9 using jdk1.8 and primefaces 6.0.  Same result where the bean validation is not working.  A copy of that tomcat project is available at: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_lsc7S7UkyuWDY1cFZsdDdlVms?usp=sharing

Comment: Btw, bean validation != Client-side validation. It is based on it, but bean validation should work in plain jsf to. If it does not work there you have a basic bean validation problem and not a PrimeFaces related one.

Comment: Ya, that is server side.  However in Primefaces showcase, they placed bean validation inside CSV. category:  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/

Comment: Yes but for you bean validation was not even working...

Comment: Pls refer to my answers, the problem is caused by the GAE restriction on initContext in jsf package.  Just need modify the LifecycleConfigProcessor class to make it work on GAE.  You are right that is not primefaces problem but is GAE restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing dependencies (i.e slf4j-jdk14, slf4j-api and jboss-el), Hibernate Validator work on Tomcat 9 but not GAE.  After configured the log level to FINER , logger show below entriies:

```
May 04, 2017 9:10:08 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor addSystemEventListener
FINE: Subscribing for event javax.faces.event.PostConstructApplicationEvent and source javax.faces.application.Application using listener org.primefaces.extensions.application.PostConstructApplicationEventListener
May 04, 2017 9:10:08 AM com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor isBeanValidatorAvailable
FINE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.InitialContext is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.InitialContext is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.isBeanValidatorAvailable(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:434)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.registerDefaultValidatorIds(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:396)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:353)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:137)
```

That is a "NoClassDefFoundError", however log in FINE level instead of Warning and return more meaningful message.  That bad.

So I make a small change to the isBeanValidatorAvailable() as below to make it work on GAE

```
static boolean isBeanValidatorAvailable() {

    boolean result = false;
    final String beansValidationAvailabilityCacheKey = 
            "javax.faces.BEANS_VALIDATION_AVAILABLE";
    Map<String,Object> appMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap();

    if (appMap.containsKey(beansValidationAvailabilityCacheKey)) {
        result = (Boolean) appMap.get(beansValidationAvailabilityCacheKey);
    } else {
        try {       
            // Code for Google App Engine 
            ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = null;
            try{                
                Object cachedObject=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get(BeanValidator.VALIDATOR_FACTORY_KEY);
                if (cachedObject instanceof ValidatorFactory) {
                    validatorFactory=(ValidatorFactory)cachedObject;
                } else {
                    validatorFactory=Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
                }       
            }catch(ValidationException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Could not build a default Bean Validator factory",e);
            }               

            if (null != validatorFactory) {
                appMap.put(BeanValidator.VALIDATOR_FACTORY_KEY, validatorFactory);
                result = true;
            }             
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "result=" +result +", validatorFactory=" +validatorFactory);

         /* incompatible with Google App Engine
          *
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("javax.validation.MessageInterpolator");
            // Check if the Implementation is available.
            Object cachedObject = appMap.get(BeanValidator.VALIDATOR_FACTORY_KEY);
            if(cachedObject instanceof ValidatorFactory) {
                result = true;
            } else {
                Context initialContext = null;
                try {
                    initialContext = new InitialContext();
                } catch (NoClassDefFoundError nde) {
                    // on google app engine InitialContext is forbidden to use and GAE throws NoClassDefFoundError 
                    if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
                        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, nde.toString(), nde);
                    }
                } catch (NamingException ne) {
                    if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.WARNING)) {
                        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, ne.toString(), ne);
                    }
                }

                try {
                    Object validatorFactory = initialContext.lookup("java:comp/ValidatorFactory");
                    if (null != validatorFactory) {
                        appMap.put(BeanValidator.VALIDATOR_FACTORY_KEY, validatorFactory);
                        result = true;
                    }
                } catch (NamingException root) {
                    if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
                        String msg = "Could not build a default Bean Validator factory: " 
                                + root.getMessage();
                        LOGGER.fine(msg);                       
                    }
                }

                if (!result) {
                    try {
                        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
                        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
                        appMap.put(BeanValidator.VALIDATOR_FACTORY_KEY, factory);
                        result = true;
                    } catch(Throwable throwable) {
                    }
                }
            }
          */
        } catch (Throwable t) { // CNFE or ValidationException or any other
            if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
                LOGGER.fine("Unable to load Beans Validation");
            }
        }
        appMap.put(beansValidationAvailabilityCacheKey, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

After all this JSR 303 (Bean Validation) problem is related to GAE restriction on JSF2.

A working copy can get from [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_lsc7S7UkyuTmdaeGgxZFNEMFE?usp=sharing).

Comment: Isn't https://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/gae-jsf-javax-naming-initialcontext-is-a-restricted-class/ a more general solution?

Comment: No at all.  That one only mention WebConfiguration class.  In fact 2 more files are require to be modified in order to get jsf 2.2.10 working on GAE which are: ByteArrayGuard and ByteArrayGuardAESCTR.  And for JSR 303 to work, extra file is require to modify as mention above: ApplicationConfigProcessor.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. 
I fixed it by upgrading `hibernate-validator` from:
`5.1.3.Final`
to:
`5.3.5.Final`

I kept Primefaces 6.1.