# Update p:inputText style while typing

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How do I update the style of a `p:inputText` while the user is typing **without interrupting their typing**?

```
<p:inputText id="radiusValue" value="#{bean.radius}"
            styleClass="#{bean.radiusStyle}">
            <p:ajax event="keyup" update="radiusValue" />
</p:inputText>
```

This is for validation.  It updates fine and gets the correct style but when the `p:inputText` updates, it sets the cursor back to the beginning... interrupting the user's entry.  There has to be a less invasive way to update the style?

Comment: What exactly is happening in `#{bean.radiusStyle}`?

Comment: And using this for validation is 'wrong' in the sense that it is not real jsf/bean validation but (most likele) checking in a setter and setting a style there. This is wrong/tightly coupled implementation and should be migrated to real bean validation. PrimeFaces can than use that in it's client-side validation which is great. Effectively you have an 'http://xyproblem.info'

Comment: @JasperdeVries If the radius passes validation then "", if not then it returns the error style.

Comment: @Kukeltje: I'm open to suggestions.  It doesn't seem like rocket science to turn a box red without resetting the whole control.  What do you mean by "real bean validation"?

Comment: Tried googling on 'jsf and bean validation' (any basic jsf tutorial has info on it)?  and e.g. the Primefaces showcase about client-side validation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740371/bean-validation-jsr-303-for-primefaces-not-working

Comment: @Kukeltje, The example you gave in the link and the javatpoint docs both require the user to "submit" the data for validation somehow. The way I'm doing it is providing validation on each key press.  Can this be reconciled? It may not be possible to update CSS without updating the field.  I should probably mention that I'm a Java dev and this is my first foray into Primefaces/JSF... my team just happened to have "the extra bandwidth". This is a massive legacy program, so I can't reimplement validation from the ground up.

Comment: @Bertmoog: No it does not... I also mentioned PrimeFaces client-side validation https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/event.xhtml. All this has been invented before ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje: That looks really neat.  I'm trying to find comprehensive documentation on clientValidator , but it's sparse. I found where you can add a custom Javascript validator, but not bean? Also, it's limited to only a red style whereas the rest of our legacy validation uses a weird orange color. There was supposed to be an update according to this :http://jsfwarriors.blogspot.com/2015/03/client-side-validation-of-primefaces.html
but I don't know if it ever happened.  Thanks for you help

Comment: I'll write a summary answer today containing the relevant parts. There really is no need for 'comprehensive documentation'. You'll see

Comment: @Kukeltje: Awesome, thanks for your time

Comment: Summary has to wait till thursday, sorry. Other priorities

Comment: @Kukeltje: No problem! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you do that validation on client?
I have not tried, but you can use `onkeyup` attribute to execute a Javascript function that adds a style class depending on what do you need.

```
function applyStyle() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myInputText");
    element.classList.add("mystyle");
}
```

Comment: If you have REAL jsf/bean/... validation, PrimeFaces CSV is doing exactly that, see the link in a comment on the question

Comment: @Blarzek: But don't you still have to update the field to get the current style to change?  I can already change the style, it just won't update until a refresh happens